mdd file does not work geometry node in simulation node
YouTube reference for this technology
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TGDlSl7QGTM&t=491s
This flow involves rewriting the fluid mesh created with the simulation node of the geometry node into an abc file, rewriting the rewritten abc file into an mdd file, importing the mdd file into the abc file, setting keyframes on the mesh, and importing it into Unreal Engine.
The mesh you want to import.

However, if it is a geometry node that does not use a simulation node, the mdd file works fine,
but if it is a geometry node that uses a simulation node, the mdd file gives an error.
What on earth is going on?
This is a simulation node

This exports the geometry nodes to an abc file.

This is importing the exported abc file into Blender.

This is exporting the imported abc file to an mdd file. An error occurs at this point.
This original mesh has a simulation node inside the geometry node, so it seems to be causing an error.
Because it works fine without using a simulation node.

And this is the ideal way.
When the mdd file works correctly,
keyframes will be created on the mesh in the abc file.

In my opinion, mdd files are files that write out the animation of mesh vertices, so I feel that files exported by simulation nodes do not have keyframes because the vertices are generated for each frame.
Is there any solution?
If it were possible to add keyframes to meshes using simulation nodes, I think there would be more freedom when transitioning from geometry nodes to game engines.
Please lend me your wisdom.

